# Customizing preview in bootstrap rich text editor?

Tags: jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4, rich-text-editor

I am using bootstrap's rich text editor, like this `$('#editor').wysiwyg();`
I am using ajax to pass html content generated by .wysiwyg in order to save to the database. I would then get the html data to paste to my homepage. The problem is I first want to show a preview text and the images inserted and show the output of the html content when the user clicks "see more". The preview looks like this:

[image]

When the user clicks "see more", that's is where I will show the full html data generated by wysiwig. In other words,in the preview section, I only want to show text without formatting along with the images I attached to it

My only solution is to directly access the html generated by bootstrap and extract the value from the textbox. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How ever as i understand

**First solution** is that you just create another **short description** functionality in your admin panel when you are posting news/article. In that short description you can only type and insert only the part you want to show in **short description** and type the full news/article in long description part.
So when want to show short part of news/article then use **short description** and use link to the **full description**.

**Second solution** is that using you server side programming just filter out the guess approximate 500 word and image and then simply show it and create a new page which link with id of full article/new to the anchor **See More**.

I hope it will give at least some idea. 
:)